# React App in Azure Web Apps gets 404 when connecting to another Node API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

My React App running on one Azure web app gets a 404 when calling the Node API running on another Azure web app. If I run the React App locally and call the Node API in the Azure web app it works.

I can also connect via POSTMAN, and CURL from the Azure development console for the React APP. CORS has been setup with Express on the Node API.

I'm thinking Web.Config but I have read 50 ish posts that all suggest to use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="favicon.ico">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".json" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I really am stuck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well, well... So did I say I was fairly new to all this!

It turns out when moving from development to production the package.json file that has `"proxy": "https://URLofTheAPI"` has no relevance in the production environment. I therefore needed to set the API URL in the get call. So instead of `axios.get('/api/hotels'...` I used `axios.get('https://URLofTheAPI/api/hotels'...`

In the meantime I learnt a lot about IIS Web.Config so the entire day wasn't lost :-) Also, it gives me my next topic to learn. How to automate the replacement of such code during the npm run build stage.